# When will Metapackage be updated to Kernel 5.6 or better

Tags: drivers, kernel, multiple-monitors

I have a Lenovo Flex 5 with a Ryzen 5 4700 and the stock Ubuntu 20.04.xxx does not see the external monitor.

The only way I have found is to install Kernel 5.6.0 and later and they works fine. But, it means I do not get updates so I have to continually check for updates to the Kernel .deb and install them manually.

I tried the AMD Renoir drivers but with 5.4.xxx they produce a bunch of other errors, but do show the external monitor, so back to Kernel 5.6.xx

When will Ubuntu move up to Kernel 5.6.0 or better?

Or fix this external monitors issue with with a Ryzen?

**BUT**, just looking through ***the*** question being asked of earlier version of Ubuntu and largely being ignored, I suspect I am stuck with .deb updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 20.10 uses kernel 5.8.

Ubuntu 20.04.2, to be released in about three months (around January 2021), will use the same kernel.

The pattern is:

- Interim releases of Ubuntu (xx.04/xx.10) occur in April and October.
- The most recent LTS point releases occur three months later (April --> July, October --> January), using the same kernel as the three-month-old interim release.

Comment: Thanks for that. I can live with the manual updating knowing relief is on the way come January.